# How do I stop the Service Fabric processes?

Tags: windows, azure-service-fabric

I used to work on a Service Fabric project.  Now I have several Fabric.exe processes running.  A couple of them take up a lot of memory.  When I try to kill them in Windows Task Manager, something starts new Fabric.exe processes.  I also have other processes with "Fabric" in the name that I don't want anymore.  Two questions:

1. How do I kill all Service Fabric-related processes for good?
2. How do I prevent these processes from starting up when I restart my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you have to remove the cluster. These are SF services used for your cluster nodes.

You can remove your cluster services via 'Cluster Manager' or via 'POwershell'.

Via **Cluster Manager**:

1. From your start menu Open the **Service Fabric Local Cluster
   Manager**
2. In the task bar tray (clock) **right-click on SF icon**
3. Select the option 'Remove Cluster'

Via **Powershell**:

Executing the following powershell script(as administrator) instead:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\CleanCluster.ps1'
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  After step #3, I right-clicked and clicked "Exit" to remove the last process.  Will this prevent the Fabric processes from starting up when I restart my computer?

Comment: I am not sure, has been a while I haven't done it, I assume it doesn't. In any case, you can go to task manager (CTRL + ALT + DEL) > startup > select 'ServiceFabricClusterManager > Click Disable

Comment: Once the cluster is removed from the local machine, the cluster will not start up even on reboot. The "Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager" will show up in the system tray but no cluster would be running.